# CakePHP: Include js file in header from view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

The cakephp docs say:

> By default, script tags are added to the document inline. If you override this by setting $options['inline'] to false, the script tags will instead be added to the script block which you can print elsewhere in the document.

So in my view file (.ctp) I have:

`echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => 'false'));`

And in my layout, in the head tag:

`echo $this->fetch('script');`

But the script tag prints out inline and not in the head.  If I miss of the echo from the line in my view file, the script doesn't print out at all in my html.

Any help would be gratefully received.

PAE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `false` in quotes, so PHP is treating it as a `string` and not a `boolean`. It should be:

```
echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => false));
```

Comment: And I stared at that for hours!  I really, really should have known better, shouldn't I?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I'd want to expand and mention a couple of things on this.

**Inline Script**

This will print out the script tag inline which isn't always desired.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('script.name'); ?>
```

**Non-Inline Script**

This will place the script where ever you placed $this->fetch('script') in your layout file, usually in the head of your page. *(As pointed out by ub3rst4r you were passing false as a string)*

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('script.name', array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

**Block Script**

This might be a much more useful version for many people, you can place a script block in any layout file (as many as you wish actually). I'll show you an example and call it scriptBottom to go before the end of my body.

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); ?>
```

Then you can pass the block to the script method like such

```
<?php $this->Html->script('script.name', array('block' => 'scriptBottom')); ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it does help.  Thanks.  I find the CakePHP book a little weak in this area.

Comment: You don't even need to `echo` the script, since it's being buffered and echoed later where the `scriptBottom` goes.

Comment: Just tested this and it worked, updated the answer accordingly, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

just put this in your view ctp file. :)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In cakephp 3 instead of array('inline' => false) you should use array('block' => true) if anyone is looking for that answer like I was. And you don't need to echo the script at the top of your ctp file you can just place inside php syntax i.e.

`<?php $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', ['block' => true]); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Why are u going on lot of attributes ?? simply use url

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: Using this in the view is going to print it inline, the view will be outside the head tag, OP does not want this.